# Java long comparison and casting

Tags: java, casting

I'm writing a piece of code that checks if packet headers for a specific kind of communication contain valid information in all fields. Right now I need to make sure that a 4-byte field has a 1 in the leftmost byte, 0 in the next byte and I don't care about the rest. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
private static boolean validateCheckSumControl(packetHeader packetHeader) {
    long mask = 0xC0000000;
    long control = packetHeader.getControl();
    long masked = mask & control;
    if (masked == 0x80000000) {
        return true;
    }
    System.err.println("Incorrect control field!");
    return false;
}
```

The mask has zeros in the first four bytes, then two one-bits and then zeros again, so and-ing it to the control field in the packet header leaves the two bits unchanged and sets everything else to zero. If the result is anything else than the first bit of the fifth byte being 1, prints an error message and returns false. The problem is that even if the control field contains exactly the value I compare it to, this code returns false. It works just fine if I replace the 0x80000000 with 0x80000000l, though.

So, here's my question - why doesn't Java perform the appropriate casting itself? Or, if it does, why does it give a wrong result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use integer constants for the mask and the value. Since they represent negative integers they get sign extended when they are converted to long values. So `0xC0000000` becomes actually `0xFFFFFFFFC0000000L` and `0x80000000` becomes `0xFFFFFFFF80000000L`. If you use `0x80000000L` it is interpreted as `0x0000000080000000L`.

Comment: Personally I strongly prefer L as the suffix because lower case l can easily be mistaken for a digit '1'

Comment: @MattCoubrough changed it to make the answer clearer.